# Duplicated tag description

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, profile-page, search

When you click on someone's profile tags, it shows a search of posts by that user on the selected tag. However, the tag description appears twice in the page and there's not much left for the actual content you want to see.

[image: Duplicated tag]

[Link to page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5771029%20[java])

The image was taken from my profile. Also not sure why it shows me a user id instead of my username.

Comment: MSO dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371566/duplicate-information-on-tag-search-page-when-users-id-is-used

Comment: *Also not sure why it shows me a user id instead of my username.* That is not a userid, it is **your** userid. There are no unique *usernames* on SE sites only displaynames. As such search can't rely on a name but instead uses your unique userid.

Comment: I checked here, MSO, and another site and I couldn't reproduce the problem there. This seems to only affect Stack Overflow (I can reproduce it there).

Comment: I'm about 90% sure this is related to Teams. Users who aren't members of a Team get a slightly different version of the search results page and it looks like we may have a copy/paste error in there somewhere.

Comment: Teams. It's always Teams.

Comment: @AdamLear not sure if there is a regression but it doesn't seem to matter whether you're on a team or not: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321670/when-searching-with-a-tag-tag-info-displays-twice#comment1052995_321670

Comment: @rene There's a non-zero chance that I'm just wrong. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the delay on this; this should be fixed next build - thanks