# When searching with a tag, tag info displays twice

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

When searching with a tag, for example [`[c++] test`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+test), the C++ tag information displays twice:

[image]

This is reproducible for me on both Chrome and Edge, but only on Stack Overflow, not on beta sites or Meta SE.

Comment: hmm... I can't reproduce this on chrome. What's your OS?

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain I'm on Windows 10 Pro V1809

Comment: Huh, I thought this was fixed by now

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using custom questions list. I'll go log out and try it.

Comment: yep, that was it. it can't be reproduced with custom questions list on.

Comment: @scohe001 are you a member of that Stack Overflow for Teams thigny?

Comment: @rene no Teams thingy for me.